# RopeVim shorcuts not working - it creates recursive mappings

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I have installed [RopeVim](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim) and I am unable to get the shortcuts working. This is where I'm at:

`g:ropevim_enable_shortcuts` is set to 1 (default value)

When I run `:map` I can see my shortcuts being mapped, here is an extract of the output:

```
...
<C-U>       * :call smooth_scroll#up(&scroll, 0, 2)<CR>
<C-C>f        :call RopeFindOccurrences()<CR>
<C-C>d        :call RopeShowDoc()<CR>
...
<C-X>pnf      :call RopeCreateFile()<CR>
<C-X>pnd      :call RopeCreateDirectory()<CR>
...
```

In this output, I've noticed that the difference between ropevim shortcuts and the rest is the `*`, which means its a non-recursive map. In fact, if add `noremap <C-X>pnf :call RopeCreateFile()` to my `.vimrc` it works!

I've tried as well different maps using  and  but I couldn't get it to work neither.

I could use that workaround and define all shortcuts are noremap in `.vimrc` but I wonder if there is a better solution

Comment: Looks like a bug in RopeVim. Can I suggest that you file an issue on the GitHub issue tracker? It shouldn't be too hard to fix it upstream to make all the mappings non-recursive...

Comment: I would say even after finding the conflict line in my config, is still worth to raise it on the RopeVim project

Comment: Yeah, especially since it's a simple fix. Make sure you mention that you had the `noremap : <nop>` mapping, it's an easy reproducer anyone can use to test this!

Answer (score 1):

After removing all my plugins and my .vimrc it worked. So I've started adding it all back and found the issue was with the second line:

```
noremap ; :
noremap : <nop>
```

I've initially added it to stop me from using ':' and force me to use the shortcut ';' instead.